# Core Data: Using a transient property decrypt and cache another value

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have created a transient property in Core Data which holds the decrypted string `formula` of a non-transient encrypted property `formulaEnc`.

I have defined a local variable `NSString *tmpFormula` to cache the decrypted formula in order to avoid decrypting the value each time the managed object is accessed.

This is the custom accessor I have added to the managed object:

```
- (NSString*)formula
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"formula"];
    NSString *tmpFormula = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"formula"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"formula"];
    
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"formulaEnc"];
    NSString *formulaEnc = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"formulaEnc"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"formulaEnc"];
    
    if(!tmpFormula && formulaEnc) {
        NSLog(@"Decryption started.");
        NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:self.formulaEnc];
        NSError *decryptionError;
        NSString *password = @"password";
        
        NSData *decryptedData = [RNDecryptor 
              decryptData:encryptedData
              withPassword:password
              error:&decryptionError];

        if (decryptionError) NSLog(@"Decryption 
              failed with error: %@",decryptionError);
        
        NSString *decryptedString = [[NSString alloc] 
                   initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        tmpFormula = decryptedString;
        [self setPrimitiveValue:tmpFormula forKey:@"formula"];
    }
    return tmpFormula;
}
```

I store all managed objects in an `NSArray` to cache it in memory. However, even though the objects are cached, whenever I read-access the managed objects, the accessor `formula` (please refer to the code snippet above) is accessed and the decryption occurs again.

BTW: This is how I create a `NSArray` of the managed objects in my main code:

```
- (NSArray*)allFigures
{   if (!_allFigures) {
        NSLog(@"Recalculating allFigures.");
        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest 
                fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Figure"];
        request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor 
                sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES ]];
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;
        NSError *fetchError;
        NSArray *result = [self.managedDocument.managedObjectContext 
               executeFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError];
        _allFigures = result;
    }
    return _allFigures;
}
```

This is how the previous snippet is called:

```
NSArray *figures = [self figuresForCategory:category
inManagedObjectContext:self.managedDocument.managedObjectContext];

[self calculateValuesForFigures:figures withCompletion:
    ^(NSDictionary *values, NSArray *figures) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

       self.figures = figures;
    });
}];

- (NSArray *)figuresForCategory:(NSString*)category 
      inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context
{  
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
            @"xyz CONTAINS[cd] %@ ",category];   
    return [self.allFigures filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
   
- (void)calculateValuesForFigures:(NSArray*)figures 
        withCompletion:(void(^)(NSDictionary* valueDict, 
        NSArray* figures))completionBlock;
{
   NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]
        initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];    
   backgroundContext.parentContext = 
        self.managedDocument.managedObjectContext;
   [backgroundContext performBlock:^{
          NSArray *figuresInBackgroundContext = 
          [self managedObjectsInArray:figures passedToContext:backgroundContext];
// …
```

When debugging the code, the local variable `tmpFormula` in the first code snippet is `nil` but should have same value as it should have been cached.

Any thoughts or ideas why my caching does not work?

### Update:

As I found out - thanks to your help, my managed objects get faulted by a unknown method. The backtrace for `-willTurnIntoFault` (command `bt` in the debugger) yields:

```
thread #24: tid = 0x8f50b, 0x000b7eb4 Demo`-[Figure willTurnIntoFault](self=0x17f18610, _cmd=0x3432fe08) + 20 at Figure.m:104, queue = 'NSManagedObjectContext Queue, stop reason = breakpoint 6.1
    frame #0: 0x000b7eb4 Demo`-[Figure willTurnIntoFault](self=0x17f18610, _cmd=0x3432fe08) + 20 at Figure.m:104
    frame #1: 0x2d8fd6ea CoreData`-[NSFaultHandler turnObject:intoFaultWithContext:] + 66
    frame #2: 0x2d9648f8 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _disposeObjects:count:notifyParent:] + 320
    frame #3: 0x2d964c16 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _dispose:] + 682
    frame #4: 0x2d95f8d2 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext _dealloc__] + 402
    frame #5: 0x2d95fb2e CoreData`internalBlockToDeallocNSManagedObjectContext + 70
    frame #6: 0x38818e7a libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_drain + 374
    frame #7: 0x38815f92 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_invoke + 42
    frame #8: 0x38819744 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 76
    frame #9: 0x388199c4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 56
    frame #10: 0x38943dfe libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 298
```

Any idea on how to find the caller of ´-willTurnIntoFault´?

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue. (But `tmpFormula` should be a local variable in that method, not an instance variable.)

Comment: @MartinR: I have added the main code which I am using to access the mo  and changed the code to use a local variable. Are you able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: No. (Of course I did not use RNDecryptor.) Are you sure that `tmpFormula = decryptedString;` is not `nil` when saving the cached value?

Comment: Any chance that the object was turned into a fault again? You could implement `willTurnIntoFault` in the entity class and set a breakpoint.

Comment: I just have double-checked that `tmpFormula` contains a valid value and added additional code to give a better overview of how I am trying to call the mo's. Could the problem relate to different managed object contexts and threads?

Comment: MartinR: Yes, you are right, `willTurnIntoFault` is being called for each mo. Do you have any idea on how I could avoid this?

Comment: Each managed object context has its own collection of managed objects. So if the transient property is set for an object in context1 then it need not be set for an object in context2.

Comment: You can consider writing some bean for caching your decryptions. Simple singleton or even global dictionary if you don't need memory freeing behaviour from your cache.

Comment: @MartinR: Do you have any idea on how to prevent the managed objects from being turned into faults? I would like to keep them in memory (their memory footprint is very low).

Comment: Why are the objects turned into faults? (Check the stack backtrace in willTurnIntoFault.)

Comment: @MartinR, the stack backtrace in willTurnIntoFault is not very helpful, e.g. it says `Thread 24, Queue NSManagedObjectContextQueue, 0 [Figure willTurnIntoFault], 1 [NSFaultHandler turnObject:intoFaultWithContext:]` … Is there a way to get better information from where the faults are triggered?

Comment: Did you try `bt` in the debugger console?

Comment: @MartinR: I have updated my question with the backtrace from the debugger console. Thank you!

Comment: It looks as if the MOC where the object was created, is deallocated. I don't yet fully grasp what your code is doing. But note that objects "live" in the MOC where they were created. If the object is created on the background MOC and the background MOC is deallocated then you pretty much can't use the object anymore. I don't know if that is what happens, but fetching *and caching* the objects in a background MOC and later using them on the main MOC cannot work.

Comment: @MartinR, it seems that you are absolutely right. When switching the calculations from the background thread to the main thread, the objects are no longer faulted.

Comment: OK. I will summarize the results to an answer ...

Comment: This is great, @MartinR! If you have some ideas on how to "transfer" the MO's from one MOC to another MOC without needing to expensively recalculate transient properties, that would be awesome.

Comment: It should be possible to transfer the objects by creating objects in the main MOC (using `objectWithID:`) and setting their transient property explicitly from the values of the "background objects". But I did not try that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for the transient property looks quite OK. `tmpFormula` should be
a local variable, and it can be simplified slightly:

```
- (NSString*)formula 
{
    NSString *tmpFormula;
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"formula"];
    tmpFormula = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"formula"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"formula"];

    if (tmpFormula == nil) {
        NSString *formulaEnc = self.formulaEnc;
        NSLog(@"Decryption started.");
        // ... decrypt ...
        tmpFormula = decryptedString;
        self.formula = tmpFormula;
    }
    return tmpFormula;
}
```

The issue is also unrelated to decryption.

The problem is that managed objects
can only live in the managed object context where they were created.

It seems that you create the objects on a background MOC and put them into a global
array for caching. But as soon as the background MOC is deallocated, all objects
are turned into faults automatically, and you cannot access their properties anymore.
(You will get `nil` or may be a runtime exception).
So this kind of caching cannot work.